# Launcher icon not loaded from mipmap folder

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I am trying to change the icon of my app. I added a new "Image Asset" which generated the different icon sizes and placed them in the mipmaps folders. (mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, ...). I added the following line to my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

But when running my app, the icon is not affected. I always get the Android default icon (which isn't even part  of my project anymore), as if I didn't specify any icon at all.

However, if I add the icon to my `drawable` directory and change the line in my `AndroidManifest.xml` to

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

it works. I tried all kinds of things, reinstalled it, restarted Android Studio, restarted my phone ...
I am quite sure that it is possible to load launcher icons from the mipmap directory. But I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Please let me know, if you need any additional information about my app. Not sure, which information could be relevant for this problem.

Comment: Also once try to use File> Invalidate Caches/ Restart..

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But that didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your icon and place it in mipmap folder. For example:- launcher_icon. Give this name into the manifest and try. Sometimes because of the cache in the Android studio this problem occurs.

Comment: I just tried it and it also didn't work... Thanks anyways!